# WPF Chromeless Window Multiple Monitor Issues

Tags: wpf, multiple-monitors

I created a WPF application that opens a second window with a window style of none. I have a thread that updates data on the chromeless window and I handle the left button down by calling DragMove to allow the window to be moved around. One monitor has 150% font scaling while the other has 200%.

If I drag the chromeless window to my second monitor, the size changes to be bigger or smaller and the updates from the background thread no longer update the UI. If I drag it back to the original monitor, the size restores and the updates resume.

If I change the style to a ToolWindow, everything works correctly; the size changes while the window is split between the monitors but corrects once moved completely and the UI updates continue. There is apparently something going on relative to moving a window around between monitors when it has a titlebar versus when it doesn't have one.

I have also noticed that without a titlebar, if after moving the window to the new monitor, I shake it causing the other windows to minimize, the window will then resize and updates will resume.

Has anyone seen this or know what I might try? If I can't find a fix then I assume I have to resort to some p-invoke magic to hide the titlebar of the tool window.